# Get colspan value of the next row

Tags: jquery

I have an html table that uses the arrow keys to navigate left, right, top and bottom.  If I go down to the next line and there is a colspan in any of the cells, I need to make adjustments so that arrowing down will take me to the correct cell.  I can't seem to get the value of the colspan of the next row.

I have tried:

```
var span = $(ctrl).closest('tr').next('tr:has(td[colSpan])').html();
```

but it just gives me the html of all of the `<td>`'s.  I can not hardcode the column that has the column span since it can be any of the first four columns.  But there will only be a max of one column span per row.  I need to get the value of that colspan w/o having to loop through each column in the row.

Comment: Shouldn't we see the markup?

Comment: try `$(ctrl).closest('tr').next('tr:has(td[colSpan])').find('td[colSpan]').attr('colspan');`

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I get an undefined using above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution in case anyone needs it.  Thanks to Arun P Johny  for leading me down the right direction:

$(ctrl).closest('tr').next('tr:has(td[colSpan])').find('td[colspan]').not('[colspan=1]').attr('colSpan')